# I want to divide image through guide in GIMP2.10.12 and slice the portion through WEB and save this action for repeated use. Pls give solutions. rgrds

Tags: gimp

Form
Prasenjit Sinha

Please give the best possible solutions.

Thanks & regards

Comment: can you [edit] your question to make it proper? I can't even understand what you want. Check [ask] for help.

Comment: Also note that GIMP doesn't have "actions".  That's a Photoshop thing.  However, you can automate in GIMP using scripts.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to routinely cut an image using guides (always the same positions?)  and save the results, I 'll suggest:

1. `ofn-preset-guides`. This lets you define set(s) of guides that you can add to your image (with a single keystroke if you define a shortcut).
2. `ofn-layer-guillotine`: works like "Slice using guides", but slices a layer into multiple layers
3. `ofn-export-layers`: exports to file all layers in the image

If your image has several layers, you'll have to flatten it (or a duplicate) first, or use `Layer>New from visible` and work on that new layer.

All these scripts are available [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/). The ZIP contains the script and a short documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To save image in  Gimp. 
File menu > Save For Web.

[image]

Follow [this](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/automating-gimp-scripts/) link for automating GIMP with scripts